# fake input that gets rendered on top of the original one in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am facing a stange issue on some android devices like Galaxy SIII(4.0.4) and HTC Desire HD (2.3.5). When I am opening a webview a fake input gets rendered on top of the original one like in the attached screenshot.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Java Code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PreferencesActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.some_dialog);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            final WebView premiumPurchasingView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.purchaseWebView);
            WebSettings webSettings = premiumPurchasingView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
            premiumPurchasingView.addJavascriptInterface(dialog, "Dialog");
            premiumPurchasingView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(PreferencesActivity.this), "Android");
            premiumPurchasingView.addJavascriptInterface(PreferencesActivity.this, "Preferences");

            premiumPurchasingView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

            dialog.show();

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    PreferencesActivity.this, 
                    getResources().getString(R.string.preloader_title), 
                    getResources().getString(R.string.preloader_content)
            );  

            premiumPurchasingView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

            });

            premiumPurchasingView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {           

                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
                      new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                              .setTitle("alert")
                              .setMessage(message)
                              .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                      new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                  int which) {
                                              result.confirm();
                                          }
                                      }).setCancelable(false).create().show();

                      return true;            
                      }
            });

            premiumPurchasingView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="redeemCode">
    <input placeholder="phone number"type="text" id="gsm_phone" size="10" onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 9) return false;" name="gsm_phone" style="margin-top:18px; padding:8px 0 9px; width:100%; background-color:#ececec;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; border:1px solid #cccccc;color:black;font-size:18px;" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: could you post the code....without that it's difficult to know what's wrong with your application..

Comment: check the post again please. I edited it.

Comment: I don't have much idea about addJavascriptInterface but I found a good post on this subject. You could go through this post if you want. here is the link http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/2011/01/21/working-with-android-addjavascriptinterface/

Comment: I don't think the issue is about javascript interface but thanks anyway.